# Find all real solutions to $8x^3+27=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

> Find *all* real solutions to $8x^3+27=0$

$(a-b)^3=a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$

$$(2x)^3-(-3)^3$$ $$(2x-(-3))\cdot ((2x)^2+(2x(-3))+(-3)^2)$$ $$(2x+3)(4x^2-6x+9)$$
Now, to find solutions you must set each part $=0$. The first set of parenthesis is easy $$(2x+3)=0 ; x=-\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$$
But, what I do not know is how to factor a trinominal (reverse of the **FOIL** method)
I know that $(a+b)(c+d)=(ac+ad+bc+bd)$. But coming up with the reverse does not make sense to me. If someone can **only** tell me how to factor a trinomial that would be great.

Comment: Also known as a "quadratic." Have you heard of the quadratic formula or polynomial discriminants? The given quadratic may not have real solutions mind you ... which can be determined with great speed if one knows about complex numbers and roots of unity, but perhaps that's for another day.

Comment: The [quadratic formula](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/quadform.htm) would tell you that your quadratic has no real roots. Note it's easier to observe that your equation is equivalent to the equation $x^3=-27/8$.

Comment: So, are you saying I should take the polynomial and get the discriminate?

Comment: $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ is what i should use for the polynomial?

Comment: There is a typo in the third line, shouldn't rise to the power of three.

Comment: The only real solution is what you've found.

Comment: @Gigili I just realized what I was fixing. There isn't supposed to be a power. Sorry for that!

Comment: $$a^3 x^3 + b^3 = 0 \implies x = -\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{b^3}{a^3}} = -\dfrac{b}{a}.$$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are working too hard. Note that
$$8x^3+27=0\iff x^3=\frac{-27}{8}\iff x=-\sqrt[3]{27/8}\iff x=-\frac{3}{2}$$
and so the only real solution is $x=-3/2$.

Comment: Why is this the only real solution?

Comment: @TheChaz Real cube roots of real numbers are unique, since $x\mapsto x^3$ is a bijection from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been a little more specific. For the sake of pedagogy, what precalculus explanation is there for why this equation has one solution, but something like $x^3-6x^2+11x-6$ has three  real solutions?

Comment: @TheChaz Well we can look at the graph of $x^3$. Or equivalently note that $x^3$ is an increasing function, so $y=x^3$ can only have one solution. I think uniqueness of cube-roots is generally taught in precalc (it was in my class, and I do not think very highly of that class).

Comment: Thanks! Sorry to hear about your precalculus experience :) Surely this answer will help the OP have a better experience.

Answer (score 3):

Using the [discriminant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_polynomial#The_nature_of_the_roots) of $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=8x^3+27$:

$$\Delta = 18abcd -4b^3d + b^2c^2 - 4ac^3 - 27a^2d^2=0-0+0-0-27(8^2)(27^2) < 0$$

Thus there is only one real root, and that is, as Alex Becker found, $x=-3/2$.

Answer (score 2):

Completion of the square yields the following.

$$4x^2 - 6x + 9 = 4(x^2 - 3/2 x) + 9 = 4(x^2-3/2x + 9/16) + 27/4 = 4(x-3/4)^2 + 27/4.$$

This definitively shows your residual quadratic can have no real roots, since its graph never goes below the line $y = 27/4.$  This representation will allow you to find the complex ones easily, if you so wish.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $-3/2$ is a solution. Then we divide $x^3+27$ by $x+3/2$. Hence we have
$x^3+27=(x+3/2)(8x^2-12x+18)=0$. But, 8x^2-12x+18 don't have real solution.